# An excited state for a molecule, Molpro, casscf

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molpro, casscf

I tried my best to bring an iodine molecule to an excited state to investigate orbital 4.3 but all my atteps were not successful. So, here is the file in molpro for the groundstate

```
    ***,mg
    gprint,orbital,civector
    memory,200,M
    angstrom

    geometry={

    I 0. 0. 1.2

    I 0. 0. -1.2
    }

    spherical

    basis={

    !

    ! iodine               (11s,10p,8d,2f) -> [6s,5p,3d,2f]

    s, I , 5899.5791533, 898.54238765, 200.37237912, 31.418053840, 15.645987838, 11.815741857, 6.4614458287, 2.3838067579, 1.1712089662, 0.32115875757, 0.12387919364

    c, 1.5, 0.24188269271E-03, 0.15474041742E-02, 0.42836684457E-02, -0.39417936275E-01, 0.96086691992

    c, 6.7, 0.75961524091, 0.42495501835

    c, 8.8, 1.0000000

    c, 9.9, 1.0000000

    c, 10.10, 1.0000000

    c, 11.11, 1.0000000

    p, I , 197.30030547, 20.061411349, 12.984316904, 9.7631460485, 3.6199503008, 2.0232273090, 1.0367490559, 0.45937816000, 0.19116532928, 0.74878813023E-01

    c, 1.4, 0.73951226905E-03, 0.66168450008E-01, 0.00000000, -0.28554662348

    c, 3.7, -0.49096186164E-01, 0.00000000, 0.38914432482, 0.65610817262, 0.31803551647

    c, 8.8, 1.0000000

    c, 9.9, 1.0000000

    c, 10.10, 1.0000000

    d, I , 119.12671745, 33.404240134, 17.805918203, 4.8990510353, 2.4516753106, 1.1820693432, 0.52923110068, 0.17000000000

    c, 1.6, 0.82596039573E-03, 0.68377675770E-02, -0.10308158997E-01, 0.22670457658, 0.44180113937, 0.36775472225

    c, 7.7, 1.0000000

    c, 8.8, 1.0000000

    f, I , 2.1800000, 0.44141808

    c, 1.1, 1.0000000

    c, 2.2, 1.0000000

    ! Effective core Potentials

    ECP, i, 28, 3 ; 4; 

    !  ul potential

    2,19.45860900,-21.84204000;

    2,19.34926000,-28.46819100;

    2,4.82376700,-0.24371300;

    2,4.88431500,-0.32080400;

    7; !  s-ul potential

    2,40.01583500,49.99429300;

    2,17.42974700,281.02531700;

    2,9.00548400,61.57332600;

    2,19.45860900,21.84204000;

    2,19.34926000,28.46819100;

    2,4.82376700,0.24371300;

    2,4.88431500,0.32080400;

    8; !  p-ul potential

    2,15.35546600,67.44284100;

    2,14.97183300,134.88113700;

    2,8.96016400,14.67505100;

    2,8.25909600,29.37566600;

    2,19.45860900,21.84204000;

    2,19.34926000,28.46819100;

    2,4.82376700,0.24371300;

    2,4.88431500,0.32080400;
    10; !  d-ul potential

    2,15.06890800,35.43952900;

    2,14.55532200,53.17605700;

    2,6.71864700,9.06719500;

    2,6.45639300,13.20693700;

    2,1.19177900,0.08933500;

    2,1.29115700,0.05238000;

    2,19.45860900,21.84204000;

    2,19.34926000,28.46819100;

    2,4.82376700,0.24371300;

    2,4.88431500,0.32080400;

    }


    {uhf

    wf,50,1,0

    orbprint,7}
```

I tried to change the active space, finding passing wf and states but it did not function at all.
here is an example

```
    {casscf

    closed,5,1,1,0,4,1,1,0;

    occ   ,7,3,3,1,5,2,2,0;

    wf,50,1,0;

    state,1;

    wf,50,2,0;

    state,1;

    wf,50,3,0;

    state,1;

    wf,50,6,0;

    state,1;

    wf,50,7,0;

    state,1;

    wf,50,2,2;

    state,1;

    wf,50,3,2;

    state,1;

    wf,50,6,2;

    state,1;

    wf,50,7,2;

    state,1;

     }

    {ci

    wf,50,1,0;

    state,1;

    save, 2100.2 }

    {ci

    wf,50,2,0;

    state,1;

    save, 2200.2 }

    {ci

     wf,50,3,0;

     state,1;

     save, 2300.2 }

     {ci

     wf,50,6,0;

     state,1;

    save, 2400.2 }

    {ci

    wf,50,7,0;

    state,1;

    save, 2500.2 }

    {ci

    wf,50,2,2;

    state,1;

    save, 2600.2 }

    {ci

    wf,50,3,2;

    state,1;

    save, 2700.2 }

    {ci

    wf,50,6,2;

    state,1;

    save, 2800.2 }

    {ci

    wf,50,7,2;

    state,1;

    save, 2900.2 }{ci;hlsmat,ecp,2100.2,2200.2,2300.2,2400.2,2500.2,2600.2,2700.2,2800.2,2900.2;option,hlstrans=2,matel=1;print,HLS=2,VLS=0}
    enddo
```

I would appreciate any help. So stupid as now I have never felt yet

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future!!!